# Should I tell my manager that I am really stressed with the project

Tags: work-environment, stress, probation, depression, employment-bond

My Father passed away last year and since then I am having issue like depression and anxiety.
And the project I am working in is making it worse. I have not slept well in weeks and started to have night sweats.
I am really stressed with my new project and don't know what to do.
I fell too much burden and feel like no one is there to help me.
I am currently working at Infosys and my probation period is still not over, there are still 6 months left. I have signed the service agreement so I could not leave the company. What should I do?
I want release from this project but it has only been 4 months. I don't want to work here anymore. Should I ask my manager about it?? Or should I go to HR? Will they help me?

Comment: I’m very sorry for your loss. When you say you “feel like no one is there to help [you]”, I don’t think this is true. I actually know your company, Infosys. Very large company. Talk to your manager, explain that you’ve been dealing a lot with personal life stress (whether you want to be specific is up to you) and you are concerned about your assignment and perhaps you need some help. There’s nothing wrong with this. Work should never be a solo mission as that could massively decrease productivity. Also seek some professional help.

Comment: As far as your mental health, talk to anyone. My girlfriend recently went through the same thing. The fact that I was there for her to cry on and talk to make her feel very grateful. Your personal life is also not a solo mission. Talk to a friend or family member or partner or religious leader or therapist or coworker. There’s help anywhere where you are. People always want other people to feel happy and will do anything to help out.

Comment: Last year is well over 4 months ago, you need to come to terms with this and don't blame a bereavement as the cause. Get professional help.

Comment: Things like this can take some time to manifest themselves, I know some people struggling months after the event, so I don't think this is that unusual. I agree to get help, though.

Comment: HR is there to protect the company.

Comment: Sorry for your loss. For someone who's been dealing with lots of anxiety and depression issues, I sincerely understand what you are going through. Believe me, you are not alone in this, you might even have coworkers who are dealing with the same stress levels and are pretty good at hiding it. First, you need to do something about it, since you need help, you must look for help, talk to a therapist, a friend, family. The more you talk about it, the less stressed you feel. Once you'll start working on it, you shouldn't expect results soon, so don't be discouraged.

Comment: If you want to talk about it to your manager, go ahead. But you should let them know that you are willing to work on it. I understand your feeling of not wanting to work there anymore, but wherever you go, you're going to get the same feeling as long as you don't know how to deal with your anxiety issues. It's going to take efforts from you, you are going to feel down and want to give up many times. But believe me, most people make it through and grow up stronger from this experience. And again, whenever you feel hopeless, talk to someone. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I ask my manager about it?

Yes, but be realistic.  Go to the manager with some idea what can be done to solve your problems.  Do you need time off?  Do you need help from somebody else for a short time (and if so, who)?

> Or should I go to HR?

No. HR don't manage projects.

> Will they help me?

It's impossible to say until you try.  Some companies care about their staff in order to get the best from them.  Others don't care and just want staff to work harder.